# Getting Elements width breaks out of while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dimensions

I'm trying to break break a chunk of text into individual lines. Each line needs to have the most number of words as possible with out growing to a width that is greater than it's container.

Using jQuery I have created a function that does so but I am having a problem with it.

Inside of a while loop I go through my chunk of text and I grab 6 words to put on a line. I want to compare the width of that text with the width of that container. But everything I try and get the width of that element it breaks out of my while loop.

I've tried using jQuery's method to get width :

```
$('element').width();
```

And the raw JS width property :

```
$('element').get(0).offsetWidth;
```

Neither seem to work but I'm not sure why? Can anyone help?

Here is a link to a jsfiddle the broken part is commented out.

http://jsfiddle.net/CZH2p/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for asking but why would you even want to do that? You can achieve this behaviour by styling the container properly, without polluting your text with <br> tags

Comment: It's to create a very specific stylized header that can only be done this way. It uses dynamic text so there is no way to break it up before the fact. Also did you look at the code? There are no br tags being added. Each line of text needs to have a background color and padding. Using inline-block or block with out breaking the text creates a solid block of color with text breaking inside of it. Using display inline you can't add padding.

Comment: Still, why is this the only way? What's wrong with fixing the header's width? (I'd like to try and help you as soon as I'm convinced it's a good idea :) )

Comment: I still belive there is a css solution to that. You should edit the question and add details on the purpose or the expected result. A bit of html and an image of the expected result would be great.

Comment: I'll get that up here asap I would love to have a CSS solution!

Comment: I don't want to rush you, but be aware that it's midnight where I live and if I fall asleep, you wait for a solution till monday :)

Comment: Here's an example image jeffpowrs.com/external-images/example.png

Comment: I see a few initial problems, the way you are referencing properties of the current object, you are just using the property name outright, not prefixed with this. And I assume you are referring to the commented out code? Which means $lastLine is an integer.

Comment: Also, the reason it just seems to be exiting the loop is because you are suppressing errors. You would be seeing an error if you weren't doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS solution to the issue:

**Version 2**

```
#a{
width: 400px;
height: 120px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
color:#fff;
background: #222;
padding: 200px 5px 0 5px;
}
#a>span{
display: block;
float:left;
font-size: 20px;
background: rgba(255,111,111,0.7);
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Wrap each word in a span tag

```
<div id="a">
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
    <span>word</span>
</div>
```

it could be done with a bit of JS

The simplest code, to give you the idea:

```
'<span>'+text.split(' ').join('</span><span>')+'</span>'
```

**Version 1**

It has a missing padding at the line break, but is close to what you wanted:

```
#a{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background: #222;
}

#a>h1 {
font-family: sans-serif;
display: inline;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 50px; /*this does the trick*/
text-transform: uppercase;
color:#fff;
background: rgba(255,111,111,0.7);
padding: 10px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="a">
    <h1>Lol'em ipsum doll or e-man and again lol'em ipsum doll or e-man</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I originally tried this route but the problem I could not solve is getting the padding at the line breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to make the spacing between words same width as the outer papddings of lines, use negative left margin on floated elements and resign from transparency in background. change opacity of the whole wrapping node instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revisit how an object works in javascript, this is also potentially better suited to a function than a plain object.

Still not sure on the purpose of what you are trying to achieve here. But this is what I can help you with.

1.
You are referencing properties of the current object without referencing the object, which means you had unknown properties everywhere.

```
$parent = $featured_el.closest('.img-wrap');
parent_width = $parent.width();
```

These create new things, not set the property you have already defined.

2.
You have an empty try catch, meaning you get no errors in your debugging console. I guess this is why you seem to be under the impression that width() is pulling you out of a loop. It's not, it's an exception being caught and suppressed.

```
} catch(err) {}
```

3.
$lastLine and last_width are never set to anything other than "0", which means your console.log always shows 0. And your call to $lastLine.text() is an error.

4.
I took a guess at what $lastLine was meant to be set to, and fixed the basic issues above. Is this now achieving what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/rakkeh/CZH2p/2/